adding event handler on event of nullable object
I'm creating some test WinForms project and trying to create items for my ContextMenuStrip at runtime. But, I can't add an EventHandler to an event ItemClicked using null-conditional operator (?.):
Why is that happening?
However if I remove null-conditional operator, it works but gives a warning: 

Will the form always have a ContextMenuStrip? Did you create it using the designer, or do you create it dynamically at run time?

Make your if condition ... && this.ContextMenuStrip != null then just access it normally (the compiler will be satisfied that you have already verified it isn't null)

This isn't anything particular to winforms or event handlers; you can't assign to something that you have accessed via ?. because that thing on the left of = might be null. Sounds more like you don't quite understand what nullable context does/how it helps you avoid null ref exceptions at runtime.. The short short version is You can tell the compiler when things might be null and when they definitely won't be, then the compiler will remind you "actually, you said this might be null and I can see you're trying to use it without checking it for null first"..

The solution here is neither of what you've tried (you have tried: "just use it without checking it, even though you told the compiler it might be null", and you tried "access it with an operator that will resolve ItemClicked as null if ContextMenuStrip is null") but instead to do something to check it isn't null and only assign an event handler if it is not null

Related: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1276

Do this
if (this.ContextMenuStrip != null)
    this.ContextMenuStrip.ItemClicked += Strip_ItemClicked;

You're having nullable compiler complaint. This is one of those sticky situations. If you had decision condition, you could get away with
if (this.ContextMenuStrip?.Enabled ?? false)

But if you know that even though your component is declared as nullable but due to logic it can't be null at this particular place in code, you can override nullable check with ! (null-forgiving) operator
this.ContextMenuStrip!.ItemClicked += Strip_ItemClicked;


Another option would be to check nullability with is for your whole if block:
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && this.ContextMenuStrip is {} contextMenuStrip){
    contextMenuStrip.Items.Add(...);
    contextMenuStrip.ItemClicked += Strip_ItemClicked;
}

